# with global.target= pip installs binaries to site-packages/bin

Tags: python, pip

As `root` I want to install packages with pip to `/usr/local/lib/python-allver/site-packages` to make them survive python version upgrades.

I defined in `/etc/environment`:

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python-allver/site-packages
```

And in `/root/.config/pip/pip.conf`:

```
[global]
target = /usr/local/lib/python-allver/site-packages
```

Before this modification the binaries were being installed to `/usr/bin`, but now they're installed to `/usr/local/lib/python-allver/site-packages/bin`. How do I make pip install the binaries to `/usr/local/bin` ?

Comment: Do you have some especially good reason to do this at all? There's no guarantee an installed package will work on another version of Python (especially in the presence of binary packages), so I'd recommend just putting in the work to make your Python package environments (virtualenvs instead of global site-packages!) rebuildable without issue.